# Load different stylesheets when packaging a war file with Grails

Tags: maven, grails, build-process, war

I want to package a Grails application for different brands. While generating a war file, I want to pass some custom parameter that refers to a certain brand and styles the application by loading the stylesheet for the brand.

I read online and one approach I found was with maven.  I tried working with maven but I am stuck while initially compiling the application. The error is

```
Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.2.1:maven-compile 
(default-maven-compile) on project foreAction: Forked Grails VM exited with error.
```

I am stuck as to what approach to take now. I searched for the above error and tried different solutions but nothing seems to work.

If there is a different way without using Maven I am willing to give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always hook into the events using `scripts/_Events.groovy` and replace the appropraite CSS/assets. The [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#4.3%20Hooking%20into%20Events) explains how to hook into build events.

Your code inside `scripts/_Events.groovy` might look something like this:

```
// This is called after the staging dir is prepared but before the war is packaged.
eventCreateWarStart = { name, stagingDir ->
  // place your code here that copies your resources to the appropriate location in the staging directory.
  Ant.copy(
    file: System.getProperty('somePassedInFile'), 
    toFile: "${stagingDir}/assets/stylesheets/whatever.css", 
    overwrite: true
  )
```

}

Then you can pass in the value of the source file from `grails prod war` like this:

```
grails prod war -DsomePassedInFile=/path/to/file.css
```

Hope this helps at least give you an idea of how you can accomplish this. (All written off the top of my head so beware of typos etc.)