# Deployment specific per-customer customizations for Grails

Tags: grails, internationalization, customization

I have the following problem to which I cannot figure out a solution, and would really appreciate some help/guidance/pointers.

We have css files, image files, and message.properies files for our product.

90% of the css, image files and message.properties are common from installation to installation.

10% is different.

What we need to do is the following:

- Create a war file for a given installation with the overrides for that installation.
- Example

  - grails create-war -customer="customerA"
  - grails create-war -customer="customerB"

Then we would have code in Grails that would apply the few differences for each Customer, which are merging in the few additional CSS rules, replacing certain images defaults, and overriding selected messages in the message.properties file.

We have got working the command-line option for creating different war files, but are struggling with  how to structure the Grails code to do the rest.

As I said, any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This might help you get started in the right direction. You will need to customize the logic about what files for which customer value but it's the same concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109013/load-different-stylesheets-when-packaging-a-war-file-with-grails/26110777#26110777

Comment: Thanks.  That is very useful for CSS, and potentially image files too.  Just need a solution for message.properties.

Comment: Same concept as the other assets. Copy the messages.properties from where ever you keep it per customer (e.g. /some/other/place/customerA-message.properties) to the target message.properties file, you can even concatenate the existing with the customer specific one if needed.

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified.  Certain customers want certain strings changed, so we have a master message.properties and other customer specific files with overrides.  Is there some way of taking a default message.properties file and changing certain keys/strings?

Comment: Using the above mentioned hook you can write any code you want in there, including opening the source message.properties file, parsing it, changing it, saving it to a new location, etc. So, yes, you can do that, but you have to write the code that does so.